# Android Webview for normal Apps

Tags: android, android-webview

Are there any issues using the Android Webview for normal apps (not games)?

pro:

- easy interaction using Javascript
- responsive and easy design with HTML and CSS
- similar to PHP in websites
- offline use is possible

cons:

- slow performance?
- some limitations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offline use is **always** possible, it's **not an added feature**.

"**Some limitations**" include no interaction with the Android system as well as no ability to use the Preferences (if done as described: only HTML + CSS + JavaScript in a WebView).
I'd say some **BIG** limitations...

Anyway, you can MIX the use of a WebView and still interact with Java code.

I, myself, develop in Java AND also use a WebView to show some structured help that uses some CSS and some JavaScript to expand/collapse the nodes.

So, well you can take advantages from both worlds:
You can have a rich HTML interface and also use the system features.